# Name for "outro" in classical pieces

Tags: style

What is the name of a passage of music that plays in classical music towards the end?  In a sense, this is the resolution of tension, or even beyond (like a denouement).

There are two examples I can cite:

- At the end of Faith No More's 'Jizzlobber', off their Angel Dust album.  Once the hard rock/metal fades out, the keyboard is the lone voice.  It plays an organ piece that you might hear at Catholic church, accompanied with a choir of voices
- The end of the self-titled Mr. Bungle album.  Dead Goon plays out with combination of orchestral pieces, light piano work, and accordion music you might hear on the banks of the Mediterranean

I want to use a term like liturgy or processional, but that's not quite right.  The term I am thinking of is roughly translated to 'music that plays while the parishioners leave the mass'.  I like to think of these pieces as palate cleansers, as catharsis.

[Here](https://youtu.be/th_KKvb9yO8?t=5m16s) is Jizzlobber, just as the heavy part fades towards the outro.
[Here](https://youtu.be/13uqg5RTAZ8?t=8m15s) is Dead Goon.  The hard music is about to end, and the outro will take over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought is "coda".

From the New Oxford American Dictionary:

> **coda** |ˈkoʊdə|
>
> noun *Music*
>
> the concluding passage of a piece or movement,
>   typically forming an addition to the basic structure.
>
> - the concluding section of a dance, especially of a pas de deux, or the finale of a ballet in which the dancers parade before the audience.
> - a concluding event, remark, or section: *his new novel is a kind of **coda to** his previous books.*
>
> ORIGIN: mid 18th century: Italian, from Latin *cauda* **‘tail.’**

See also:

- ["Coda" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_(music))
- ["Coda" in the *American Heritage Dictionary*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=coda)